# How to find the right specification of LED corresponding to an incandescent bulb to replace the latter?

Tags: led, calculation, incandescent

I have a motorcycle and its taillight had an incandescent (filament) bulb. The wiring diagram says it's specification was 18W for 12V supply. Now, I want to use an LED (or several) in its place with almost same net brightness (which is around 200 lumens as a calculator on a website tells). How do I determine of what rating should the LED (or LEDs) be in order to get such brightness, that I can also fit in that circuit?

I also want to play on the safe side and don't burn the LED if the current fluctuates a little bit. And, I don't have a multimeter.

Comment: 18 W is very unusual. I don't ride a motorbike but a quick web search indicates that they're 5 or 6 W for the tail lamp and 21 W for the brake light, same as a car. Why would you not fit an LED replacement bulb?

Comment: To rephrase what @Transistor is saying -- if the original bulb is of standard type, then there should be an LED replacement for it.  So just bung that in and be happy.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, I found *"I don't have a multimeter"* a bit off-putting. The only possible answer, if you can't even be bothered to get and learn to use a multimeter, is to just buy something. And that wouldn't be a question for here.

Comment: I don't consider the multimeter comment off-putting.  I think OP was just trying to head off suggestions that start off with "first grab your multimeter and measure...".

Comment: @Transistor, actually taillight is 12W and brakelight is 18W. If I learn how to make something for 18W, 12W will be no problem. I have tried to fit a replacement LED that comes in market for my model, but they come with flimsy wires and have a very short life, maybe intentionally so. So I want to make something robust from scratch myself.

Comment: I think we need a photo. I have never seen a motorcycle bulb that had wires. You should also give the make and model of the bike.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use a *raw LED* unless you actually know how to do electronic design around raw LEDs. They don't work like normal bulbs at all.    Presumably you will use a pre-designed, pre-manufactured product which includes a lamp socket, electronics, heat sink, lens and LED emitters proper.  These are consumer products and recommending them is off-topic here.  (Nowhere on StackExchange recommends light products).  However, those products will have a specification color temperature, CRI and lumens - just match and match.   These products will take care of regulation for you. Most of them are using buck conversion to accept anything from 12V to 24V and possibly 30V or more.  As such, surges of say, 24v won't bother them one bit.

If you have the electronics chops to "roll your own", then you pick the lowest battery voltage you ever expect to see, make your series LED string below that voltage (3 white LEDs, maybe 5-6 red ones) and then buck convert down to that voltage - or really, current, since LEDs like constant-current. You can make it as spike tolerant as you please.

However, there's a gotcha.  If the lamp on the vehicle has a colored lens, what that lens does is *destroy* all lumens of light, except the lumens of light which are its color.  So a red lens is destroying all light which isn't near red.  That might be 70% of the total lumens made by a white light.  *However, it will be 0% of the total lumens made by a red LED!*

So you have to be careful to not get a "lumen overload" by selecting a red LED of same lumens as the white light.  That will give you 3-4 times the lumens you intended!

You must also be careful with lensing.  The stock incandescent has the filament in a *very specific place*.  The lensing and reflectors (typically Fresnel lenses) are designed to take spherical light from that place, and redirect the light to the correct location.   If your make a ham-handed effort at LED substitution, the light source will be in the wrong place and it will not go properly through the lenses, resulting in light going to the wrong places and not to the right places. So it may be a great deal dimmer in the directions that matter.

Sometimes the reflector plays an important role.  For instance, a classic "Golden Glow" headlamp makes almost all the directional "beam" using the reflector. An LED intended for Golden Glow might be entirely down-facing emitters aiming to bounce light off the reflector.  Your LED doesn't need to make a full sphere of light, but you do need to make sure that it covers the right angles.